# SUMIF a value, that is the result of a =RIGHT() Function, Copy/Paste-able

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm looking to sum up the results of a =RIGHT() Function(multiple numbers going down the G Column), that is a time 00:00:00, but it counts it as text, instead of numbers. I need a formula that can add the time, based on a name, and can copy/paste it into different boxes, as where I need them to be, aren't on the same page/row.

I tried to use =SUMIF(A3:A,G3,VALUE(F3:F)) But I obviously can't do that, as it only counts the last section as a single range.. I was hoping, initially, that if I had formatted the time cells as a duration, it would count it as numbers.

Here's a test sheet, in my actual use case, it can't just go down the line, as that's not how my other sheets are, so it would have to be able to be copy/pasted next to each name. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jizHBZO8yD4-VoCQamk9m_BhcOpvq1vWct7Jy1XNm3s/edit?usp=sharing

The first page would have a long line of trainings, that get dynamically added from a google form, and I have 3 pages I need to copy/paste the formula to. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula-

```
=IFERROR(SUM(FILTER(INDEX(--('Training Times'!$C$2:$C$18)),'Training Times'!$A$2:$A$18=A2)),0)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this provided formula, and tried to edit it to my specifics, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I added some extra context within the spreadsheet, along with the formula I'm specifically using.